# Communication between a server and unity app

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, server

I'm developing an android game using unity. I have a pi-server (static ip, port forwarding, apache 2, php, mysql and phpmyadmin all set up) and I want to use it to store scores from my app to it as well as retrieve  top scores for a leader-board. What code should I use to facilitate the kind of communication I want? To be more precise how would I send through the sql code to the server and read the data?

It is the first time I'm attempting to do this kind of thing, so sorry if it is something obvious. Other info: port 80 is set for forwarding, the database is called "game_scores", table is called "highscore" and the table consists of 4 columns: id, username, score and date.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's possible to have your app communicate directly with the MySQL database on your server ([through port 3306](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-standard.html), not port 80), the standard way to facilitate this kind of connection is to instead implement a web service (REST API) that runs on your server, listens for HTTP requests from your Unity app, and connects to the database to respond to your app with the data it needs. Communicating with your server through HTTP (or similar protocols) creates an abstraction layer that allows you to change or swap out your server or database implementation in the future without changing the client. [Here's a decent-looking tutorial](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html) that describes how to create a simple REST API with PHP and MySQL. Once you create the REST API on your server, you can send requests to it from Unity using [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html).